# Text box added at runtime will not get focus

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, textbox, focus

I have created a user authentication form at runtime that is supposed to have focus when it is loaded. I want to have focus on the first textbox which is for the username, but when the form loads both the form and textbox do not have focus. If I click on the form then the focus will be set to the appropriate textbox.

```
Form frm = Variables.FormCntrls.fmAuth;

            frm.Width = 315;
            frm.Height = 175;
            frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            frm.TopMost = true;
            frm.BackColor = Color.Black;
            frm.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            frm.Opacity = .9;
            frm.Name = "userAuthentication";
            frm.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            frm.KeyPreview = true;
            frm.Visible = true;
            frm.Enabled = true;

            Label lb = new Label()
            {
                Text = "User Authentication",
                Width = frm.Width - 20,
                Height = 30,
                TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
                Left = 10,
                Top = 10,
                ForeColor = Color.White,
                Font = new Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Underline)
            };
            frm.Controls.Add(lb);

            lb = new Label()
            {
                Text = "Username: ",
                AutoSize = true,
                TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
                Left = 10,
                Top = lb.Bottom + 20,
                ForeColor = Color.White,
                Font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
            };
            frm.Controls.Add(lb);
            TextBox tb = new TextBox()
            {
                Name = "user",
                Width = 200,
                Left = lb.Right + 2,
                Top = lb.Top,
                ForeColor = Color.Black,
                TabIndex = 1,
            };

            frm.Controls.Add(tb);
            tb.Select();


            lb = new Label()
            {
                Text = "Password: ",
                AutoSize = true,
                TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
                Left = lb.Left,
                Top = lb.Bottom + 20,
                ForeColor = Color.White,
                Font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
            };
            frm.Controls.Add(lb);
            tb = new TextBox()
            {
                Name = "pass",
                Width = tb.Right - (lb.Right + 2),
                Left = lb.Right + 2,
                Top = lb.Top,
                ForeColor = Color.Black,
                PasswordChar = '*',
                TabIndex = 2,
            };
            frm.Controls.Add(tb);

            Button btn = new Button()
            {
                Name = "UserAuthenticationBtn",
                Width = 75,
                Height = 30,
                Left = tb.Right - 75,
                Top = tb.Bottom + 15,
                Text = "Login",
                BackColor = default(Color),
                UseVisualStyleBackColor = true,
                TabIndex = 3,
            };
            btn.Click += new EventHandler(controlActions.btnActions.btnAuthorize);
            frm.Controls.Add(btn);

            btn = new Button()
            {
                Name = "Cancel",
                Width = 75,
                Height = 30,
                Left = btn.Left - 85,
                Top = tb.Bottom + 15,
                Text = "Cancel",
                BackColor = default(Color),
                UseVisualStyleBackColor = true,
                TabIndex = 4,
            };
            btn.Click += new EventHandler(controlActions.btnActions.btnCancle);
            frm.Controls.Add(btn);

        }
    }
```

Any help with this would be great. I am sure I am just missing a simple detail somewhere.

Comment: cannot reproduce your problem. your code works like a charm, I can start typing immediately into the first textbox. Although I changed `Form frm = Variables.FormCntrls.fmAuth;` to `Form frm = new Form();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this when you create the control:

```
tb.Focus();
tb.Select();
```

Comment: I have tried that and it does not seam to work. I think the problem is that the form does not have focus for some reason after it loads. If I click on the form it will focus to the desired textbox.